# Elasticsearch how to index text files using the command line

Tags: elasticsearch

I started playing with Elasticsearch. I want to create index for a textfile. I mean that I have multiple text files in a folder. I want to create  index on these text files so that I can perform text search on these files. Is there a way to do this using command line or . Please guide me with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can by using the FS river + mapper attachment plugin. [Here is a link](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver) to the source page.

I ran a few tests with it a little while ago. It works fine. Be aware though, that the file has to be local for this to work (even if you can mount a remote file to a local path).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fair enough!! Thanks Sir!!

Comment: As An extension I just wanna ask if I could Index files on HDFS using the FS river or I WOULD require a diffrent kind of plugin or river

Comment: I do not know if it answer your question, but the files just have to be locally present on the computer running es. You can, in windows, use a distant folder mounted as a local drive. I've been testing that and it works. Unix/Linux should have the same feature (ie : mounting a distant folder). So, you can just mount the same distant folder on the same path on all your cluster's computers, to solve the inability to use a distant folder.